# IF statement invalid syntax message

Tags: python, if-statement

How can I change the IF statement? I only get invalid syntax

```
predicted_sentiment = [if score < 0 then 'Negative', if score == 0 then 'Neutral' if score > 0 then 'Positive' for score in sentiment_polarity]
```

Comment: You've tagged this question with Python, but that's not Python. That's not how if statements work in Python. It looks like pseudocode, and you're expected to fill in the *actual* syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
predicted_sentiment = [
    ('Negative' if score < 0 else 'Neutral' if score == 0 else 'Positive') 
    for score in sentiment_polarity
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda that would increase readability (a bit subjective) and simplifies the way you can test it (more objective)

```
>>> c = lambda x: 'Negative' if x < 0 else 'Neutral' if x == 0 else 'Positive'
>>> c(2)
'Positive'
>>> c(-2)
'Negative'
>>> c(0)
'Neutral'
>>> sentiment_polarity = [1, 0, -2, 3, -4]
>>> predicted_sentiment = [c(s) for s in sentiment_polarity]
>>> predicted_sentiment
['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative', 'Positive', 'Negative']
```

#### edit

You can also use `numpy.sign()` like this

```
c = lambda x: ['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive'][numpy.sign(x)+1]
```